# Query Membership of Active Directory Group in Security Group in Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, active-directory

I have a Sharepoint group, and within this group, is an Active Directory group.  I want to know if I can send a query to find if the current user is a member of the AD group, from Javascript.  I do not want to go down the path of needing to copy the members of the AD group to a SP group, so I want to know if I can simply query against the AD group from Javascript.

Comment: You would need to query from JS -> Active Directory. SharePoint has no knowledge of who is in that group until a specific user is enumerated against the group (e.g. they attempt to access the SharePoint resource).

Comment: Have you any information on how to query Active Directory from Javascript? Looking around I have failed to find information on how to do that.

Comment: Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319249/how-do-i-do-an-ldap-query-with-javascript, JavaScript won't be able to.

Comment: This is unfortunate news, I suppose from here the next step would be to set up some codebehind on my aspx page to access AD

Comment: Yep, some SSOM code would do the trick. There you can use the System.DirectoryServices namespace.

Comment: I am new to working with CodeBehind, especially in the context of Sharepoint.  Are there any resources/tips you could offer before I close this question?

Comment: [Creating Application Pages for SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231581.aspx). I'd also recommend [Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C).

Comment: That will be very helpful for reference! Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can query AD membership using this workaround:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var groupId = 5; // the group membership ID for the group you want to check
var group = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups().getById(groupId);
clientContext.load(group,"CanCurrentUserViewMembership");
clientContext.load(group,"OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership");
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function(sender,args){
        var isMemberOfGroup = group.get_canCurrentUserViewMembership() && group.get_onlyAllowMembersViewMembership();
        if(isMemberOfGroup){
            doSomething();
        }
    },
    function(sender,args){"Whoops! "+alert(args.get_message());}
);
```

Solution thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164019/user-is-part-of-an-ad-group-that-is-nested-in-the-sharepoint-group-how-to-relate

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately AD cannot be queried in any way via Javascript, so the alternative I will pursue is using codeBehind to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it via javascript, create a page or some other securable object, secure it with the desired SharePoint group, then try to ajax it. It should then force a check if the user has access (by way of the AD group in your SP group).

Based on the response code, do what ever you need to do.

Comment: What exactly would I be ajaxing here? Just trying to get the object or page at all? Then if it succeeds that means that the current user exists in the AD group?

Comment: Correct, you could create a single page (it doesn't need content, just to be a major version and be approved) or a text file secured as desired and try to AJAX it. If  it returns a 404, they don't have access.

Comment: This is a very interesting idea, I did not know that Sharepoint would force the check.  I'll definitely give this a shot!